# Oracle can't use value default if parameter is null

Tags: c#, oracle

I have Stored Procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  TestApi  (  
     p_Contract IN varchar2,
     p_ObjID IN INT DEFAULT 0, ------ This Question
     p_Result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
     --p_Message OUT varchar2
) IS
    p_Message varchar2(500);
Begin
    IF p_ObjID =0 THEN p_Message:= `Null`;
    ELSE  p_Message:=`Not Null`;
    END IF;
    Open p_Result For 
         Select ID as "SupportListID", 
                p_ObjID as "ObjID" 
         FROM SupportList
         where rownum<=5 ;
End ;
```

To run:

```
 VARIABLE p_Result REFCURSOR;
 EXEC PAR.TESTAPI('PPHP0001',null,:p_Result); 
 -- If i don't set Parameter with NUll , execute will cause an error 
 print p_Result;
```

Result:

```
 SupportListID ObjID                                   
------------- --------------------------------------- 
107*******                                            
107*******                                            
107*******                                            
107*******                                            
107*******
```

My Question : I execute SP with 1 parameter `NULL` , SP can get `DEFAULT VALUE`
NOTE : IF i  use any type data except `REFCURSOR` , i can get `DEFAULT VALUE` . Tell me how to do that  . I use `OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` `C#` to get parameter from SP Oracle

Update : I finished, use BybindNameof OracleCommand, Thanks so much everybody

Comment: Why would it use the default for the parameter? You have provided a value and the value is `NULL`; which means an unknown value and does not mean "no value so use the default".

Comment: No No, In C# Code i just use parameter for Parameter's Oracle without Default value.
SP will retrieving data from C# If it exist ,and SP will use Default Value if don't pass it to SP. 
You know what I mean ???

Comment: If you want help with the C# code then you will need to post your current code (and where it is causing issues).

Answer (score 3):

Simply use named parameters and omit `p_ObjID`:

```
VARIABLE p_Result REFCURSOR;
EXEC PAR.TESTAPI(p_Contract => 'PPHP0001', p_Result =>:p_Result);
```

Comment: The OP stated "I use OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters C# to get parameter from SP Oracle". This does not answer how to do use named parameters (or default values of parameters) in C#.

Comment: @MT0 So OP, could easily add `if` statement and do not bind parameter in C# if it is `NULL`.

Comment: But If SP add one more parameter with default value , i must change C# Code, How to do it without changing C# code . So can't cause an error . Thanks